# Using ffmpeg to change camera settings on Linux machine

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, linux-mint, webcam

I am very new to ffmpeg but I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/access-advanced-settings-for-the-integrated-webcam-on-windows-10/) to fix my camera settings on my Windows machine ever since the built in advanced settings disappeared.
Recently the webcam on my Linux machine (Linux Mint 19) has started showing a very dark image and I was hoping to use this same approach to solving it, as ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 (latest supported version for my OS) is already installed.
The commands I use on Windows are:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy -hide_banner ## To list the names as I can never remember.
ffmpeg -f dshow -show_video_device_dialog true -i video="Device name" ## To open the advanced settings GUI on Windows
```

This does not work on Linux as a number of the commands are OS specific. Though I have tried I can not find the solution to my problem clearly in the documentation. Is it not possible to use ffmpeg to achieve this on Linux or how can I do it? I do not mind if it is not a GUI but terminal input, as long as I can access the settings.

Comment: `guvcview` has brightness control

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it made me realize I can use my screen recording tool to adjust the settings manually.